# amChart clustered-column-chart labels are not related with columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, amcharts

I am using amchart5 with React and based on [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/clustered-column-chart/) demo decided to create clustered vertical chart. 
if I give "500px" as width it would be like
[width:"500px"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49lfA.jpg) 
if I give "400px" or less it would be like
[width:"400px" or less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qnwX.jpg) 
as you see place of labels like 2021 or 2021 changed ... 
so how can I fix this? **I want to give differents width and it will work without this problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default gradiant size of this chart demo is big that's why labels would be hidden.
Added **minGridDistance** to my xAxis like this:

```
const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "x",
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
      cellStartLocation: 0.1,
      cellEndLocation: 0.9,
      minGridDistance: 20,
      maxWidth: 150,
    }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
  })
);
```

and it solved!